# Programa dá crash após alocação na pilha e chamada em C

Tags: windows, assembly, intel, x64

Estou tentando fazer um simples programa: aloca na pilha um inteiro, chama `scanf` da biblioteca em C e o imprime na tela. **Já fiz disassembly do mesmo em C**, e tento reimplementá-lo, sem sucesso. Testei a alocação sem fazer qualquer chamada em C, sem qualquer erro. O problema é a convenção x64 da Microsoft. O que há de errado com o seguinte programa?

```
bits 64
section .data
local1 db 'Hello. Input a number, please.',10,'> ', 0
local2 db '%u', 0
local3 db 10,'You input: %u', 0

section .text
extern printf
extern scanf
extern exit
extern getch

global WinMain
WinMain:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov dword[rbp - 4], 0
    ; = push dword 0 em 64 bits 
    mov rcx, local1 
    call printf ;imprime o "pedido"
    mov rcx, local2
    lea rdx, [rbp - 4] ;endereço da variável alocada
    call scanf
    mov rcx, local3
    call printf
    call getch
    xor rcx, rcx ;coloca o valor de saída como 0
    call exit ;sai
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp ;stack frame de saída
    leave
```

PS.: (Considere | uma quebra de linha) Já tentei trocar `mov dword[rbp - 4], 0` por `sub rsp, 4 | mov dword[rsp-4], 0` e `push word 0 | push word 0` (`push dword` é ilegal em 64 bits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você comparou o código gerado pelo compilador com o código que você escreveu? Se colar aqui o assembly gerado, pode ajudar.

De qualquer forma [antes de chamar uma função você deve alocar espaço na pilha para 4 parâmetros](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/x64-architecture), aqueles que são passados em rcx, rdx, r8, r9, mesmo que haja menos parâmetros.

Assim a função chamada terá espaço para "derramar" (spill) na pilha os valores passados e usar esses registradores para outras coisas (para chamar outras funções, obter ponteiros para esses parâmetros, etc.)

Vi que você só falou em `sub rsp, 4`, que avança a pilha em 4 bytes (para o seu inteiro, e nada para os parâmetros), o que é insuficiente. Além disso, a pilha tem que ficar [alinhada em 16 bytes](https://web.archive.org/web/20160427200455/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew5tede7.aspx) entre chamadas de função. Lembrando que call faz push de 8 bytes, então [cada função deve ajustar a pilha com 16n+8 bytes para restaurar o alinhamento](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/2004/01/14), sendo `n` o número de variáveis de 64 bits que você quer.

Então sugiro começar a função com `sub rsp, 88` (16*5 + 8, deixando assim espaço para 5 valores, 4 para as chamadas e 1 para sua variável local) e esquecer todo o resto da manipulação de pilha (usar só mov daí em diante).

Se for fazer push do rbp, ele deve servir como o `+ 8` da fórmula acima, então só precisaria `sub rsp, 80`.

Obs.: trechos de código não testados.

Comment: Marcus, era exatamente isso: sub rsp, 80. Não sabia por que, e achei que era coisa do compilador (haviam diversas labels apenas do compilador)

Comment: Ah, esqueci de dizer que para equilibrar a pilha no final da função precisaria desfazer todos os passos em ordem contrária. No caso seria um `add rsp, 80`, embora nesse caso não deve ser obrigatório porque o programa termina antes disso, já no exit.

Comment: como eu manípulo a minha variável? Devo usar rbp - 4 ou rbp - 76 ?

Comment: Os parâmetros devem ficar no topo da pilha (endereços de memória de menores) quando é feito um call. Então as variáveis locais de cada função devem ter endereços maiores (obs.: estou sem tempo para dar uma resposta mais detalhada, depois me diz se conseguiu)

Comment: Como esperado, rbp - 76. O único fato que não entendi é: por que tenho que alocar uma variável local de tamanho 16? Não posso alocar simplesmente uma de 4?

Comment: Opa, certeza que é rbp - 76? Dá uma olhada nos diagramas destes sites:
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/ e https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300794.aspx

(o primeiro fala tanto de Linux quanto do Windows, cuidado pra não confundir)

As variáveis locais ficam mais "perto" do rbp (portanto, rbp - 4) e depois (depois significa "endereços menores", não mostrado nos diagramas) vem o local dos parâmetros (não respondi isso ontem porque estava com pressa e ia confundir tudo).

Comment: A pilha tem que ficar alinhada em 16 bytes. Provavelmente porque permite um desempenho melhor (garante que os bits menos significativos serão sempre 0). A menos que sua função não chame nenhuma outra (ou seja, se sua função for uma leaf function), nesse caso ela pode fazer o que quiser com a pilha! Claro que você pode encontrar outro lugar para guardar sua variável. Lembre-se que: a função que chamou a sua deve ter alocado 16*4 bytes em rbp + XXXX, e que você não é obrigado a usar o rbp (pode usar o rsp pra tudo), podendo alocar esses 8 bytes pra outra coisa.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21034/discussion-between-marcus-and-lucas-henrique).